# How to get pyautiogui to take a screenshot and search for image within the screenshot and click on the image?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm trying to click on a virtual machine, but for this I need to use pyautogui.screenshot and I need to click on an image within the screenshot.

I tried to use pyautogui.screenshot, locate image, and pyautogui.click, but it can't find the image.